# How to save an image in inches with a resolution?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fabricjs

Is there any way to set resolution with fabricjs when saving an image to my computer?
Because i need an image with height and width in inches to print it in paper, but when i saved the image and open it in a program, it's opened with a 72 resolution given by default for the browser and i need a 300 resolution for print but preserving my width and height in inches.

Comment: Can you include your code? It will help.

Comment: sure, here's fabric's code `     $("#save_text").on('click', function (e) {
                $.post(ruta,
                {
                    respuesta: canvas.toDataURL({format: 'jpeg'})
                },
                function (data, status) {
                 
                });` sending through an ajax request and just saving the image with php ` file_put_contents("images/" . $fileImage, base64_decode($img));` but i said it saves with a 72 resolution and i need to be a 300  resolution for print.